Breaking a Region Which Is not V-simple into V-simple Regions
So say I have some region which is not V-simple, where V is some variable. For example,
a heart shape(made of two semicircles atop a triangle) is not x-simple because a horizontal line above the triangle intersects the two semicircles at four different points. However, if one draws a line splitting the heart down the middle, then the two halves are x-simple.
Is there an algorithm or method which can be implemented by a computer program such that, given a non-simple region represented by a set of functions and bounds, one can generate lines such those lines break the region down into simple regions? If not, has it been proven that this is impossible?
Thank you
